# How can I deploy .NET v4.0 application on target environment without .NET v4.0?

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, task-parallel-library

How can I deploy .NET v4.0 application to some target servers where installing .NET v4.0 is not an option? Recompiling to v3.5 is not feasible too because I have been using Task Parallel Library. Should I use NGen.exe? Does anyone have the experience?

Comment: This reeks of "Not a real question" because by your own admission you can't do what you want. Fire will never give off cool. My ceiling fan will never be the reason to cause rain in the Sahara desert. It ain't gonna happen.

Comment: Duplicate of "How can I install my App on a table without a PC?" but I can't find it right now.

Comment: @drachenstern: I was agreeing with you up until the ceiling fan part. Obviously you've never heard of the [butterfly effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_effect) ;-)

Comment: @CodyGray lol, I put that there for that reason ;)

Comment: @drachenstern: Then you give the asker false hope! The task he seeks to achieve is actually impossible.

Comment: Simple Solution - Don't use Task Parallel Library and you are golden, you can do parallel programming without said library, people have been doing it for many years.  I don't see how NGen.exe would help in this situation.  Of course installing .NET 4.0 is an option, there is really no reason not to install it, you can have both .Net 3.5 and 4.0 installed.

Comment: @Ramhound: "Simple Solution" is a tad subjective. Yes, people have been doing it for many years, but it sucked. If you could just drop the TPL and fall back to what you've been using for years without much hassle, it would mean the TPL was a pile of junk.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't.  If there is a dependency on .net 4 then the framework must be installed as well.

Your only options are:

1. Convincing the server owners to install .net 4
2. Remove usage of any 4.0 framework dependencies and retargetting your application.
3. Deploying to different servers that do have .net 4 installed.

Comment: You deserve a couple of badges ;-) +1

Comment: @Klaus: Thanks.  I'm not sure whether to be happy that I hit my daily rep cap after only 10 minutes of being on the site today or sad because it means I should find something else to do.. ;)

Comment: @Chris: why would that mean you should find something else to do? Forget the rep, keep going!

Comment: Hehe, I don't know either... maybe go grab a beer from the fridge and answer a few more questions? ;-)

Comment: @Martinho:  There's always the bounty questions.. :)

Comment: @Chris You mean you actively see new bounty questions that can be answered sanely? :P

Comment: @drachenstern: Well.. That's a whole 'nother issue entirely.  Just adds to the difficulty level.

Comment: I'ld give you a +1 but I don't the badge or upvote will influence you :p

Answer (score 4):

You cannot. An application compiled for framework 4.0 will require framework 4.0 to run. Alternatively you can expose the functionality written for framework 4.0 through webservices and consume them through a 3.5 client.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I deploy .NET v4.0 application
>   to some target servers where
>   installing .NET v4.0 is not an option?

You do not. Point. They also can not run Linux or MAc software.

> Does anyone have the experience?

Yes. I dont deploy it. If it is a customer - no way. If it was my job to make the software for them to run, I get fired, as I should for not asking first.

Comment: "They also can not run Linux or MAc software." Why so? Are applications compiled for Microsoft's .NET 4.0 not runnable under the latest Mono (2.8 I think)?

Comment: Mono is not a direct port there are many things that do not work in it.

Comment: It really depends on the features of .NET 4 being used. In general this is acceptable.

Comment: Yeah I thought the Linux / Mac statement was a bit out of place.